# Finding All Paths in this Directed Graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I have recently discovered graphs and algorithms and am trying to solve a specific problem involving two different types of vertices: Users and Entities.  Details are as follows:

- The graph is directed
- I am trying to find all paths from A to B
- A is always a User
- B can be a User or an Entity
- If B is a User, maximum depth for the search is 3 edges
- If B is an Entity, maximum depth is 2 edges
- I can not traverse any edges which are outbound from a User, unless the user is A

Although the graph has two types of vertices, it is not bipartite.

So far I have managed to create a graph object which holds a vertex-indexed array of adjacency lists.  The adjacency lists are based on linked lists.

I think I require some kind of variation on an All Paths algorithm, but I'm not quite sure.  In addition, not sure whether I should be looking at DFS or BFS.

I am working in PHP, which complicates matters, since most examples are in Java.  What I'd really like is the pseudo code.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Andrew, the input will be a list of edges, u->v.  The output will be a list of paths, such as A->B, A->X->B, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're traversing some sort of LDAP implementation.  If you need a generic algorithm, just use a DFS, since it's easier to code.  Doing this is overkill though unless the depth will change.

Most generic way

```
 dfs(A,B):
     return dfs(A,B,1);

 dfs_(u,B,depth):
     if u == B:
          return u;

     if (u is User and depth > 3) or (u is Group and depth > 2):
          return None;       

     out = [];
     for children of thing:
          return max( dfs_(children,depth+1) ) # take the non-null one
     out.append(u);
     return out;
```

Comment: Thanks dfb.  Logically similar to LDAP, but using a relational DB.  What to you mean it's overkill unless the depth will change?  Is there a better way to approach the problem when the graph is not deep?

Comment: I might just hardcode the traversal or do something more specific to the task since the logic is fairly simple... just a thought